# Using SuperpoweredSDK in iOS

Tags: ios, audio

I've downloaded [SuperpoweredSDK](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine) to add audio filters. I'm new to this audio stuff and don't know a pie about this filter stuff. I want to save (applied filter) audio file. How do I do this?

Ok, after spending a day in finding their way of working, I found a demo sample which is actually applying Time Stretching filter.

Now I want filter for following types,

1. Echo (Delay)
2. Reverb
3. Pitch Shifting
4. FadeIn / FadeOut
5. Equalizer

Can someone provide sample code for all of the stuff?

If you're good at C++ code and AudioFilters logic please check Superpowered offline processing example you may answer to my question easily.

Comment: What have you tried and what problems have you encountered? Everyone here on SO would be glad to help you with your bugs and errors, but it is not a go-to place for ready solutions. I'd suggest you read up on audio filters and try implementing them yourself.